# how to select image from expo-image-picker react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I try to select image from gallery and show it on Image component. I read the expo documentation and follow the step . when I try it on web it's work. but when I try it on android phone , after I select image and crop my app redownloading . I don't know where  make mistake

- my code .............................

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    
    import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
    import { Button, Image, View, Platform } from 'react-native';
    
    
    
    export default function GalleryComponenet() {
        const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
        
        useEffect(() => {
            (async () => {
            if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
                const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
                if (status !== 'granted') {
                alert('Sorry, Camera roll permissions are required to make this work!');
                }
            }
            })();
        }, []);
        
        const chooseImg = async () => {
            let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
                mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
                aspect: [4, 3],
                quality: 1,         
                allowsEditing: true,
            });
        
            console.log(result);
        
            if (!result.cancelled) {
              setImage(result.uri);
            }
        };
        
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', }}>     
                <Button title="Choose image from camera roll" onPress={chooseImg} />
                {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Comment: This is working for me perfectly. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/p0wO9vm.jpg) of the result.

Comment: but i my app crash?

Answer (score 0):

i couldnt find your mistake, but just finished making function that picking image from the gallery and return her uri.

```
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
import { Platform, Alert } from "react-native";

export default async function getPhotoUri() {
  if (Platform.OS !== "web") {
    const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== "granted") {
      Alert.alert("OOPS!", "Premmision denied", [{ text: "ok" }]);
    } else {
        const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3],
        quality: 1,
      });
      if (!result.cancelled) {
        return result.uri;
      }
    }
  }
}
```